# C# XCeed Word. Можно ли создать таблицу в фиксированном месте?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Использую теги в шаблоне `Word` документа.
Сейчас все теги я подменяю на значения. Скажем `*_№-документа_*` - подменяю на `"31"`. `*_Дата_*` - на сегодняшний день и тут окей.
Появилась надобность создавать таблицу в месте с `*_таблица-1_*` (условно).
Я могу без проблем отыскать это слово и на его основе сгенерить таблицу, но не знаю как ее можно(и можно ли) поставить именно в нужное место.

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: А почему бы сразу в шаблоне не создать готовую таблицу?

Comment: @aepot потому что этот код будет применяться к шаблонам разных видов, но с одинаковыми тегами

Comment: В любом случае, рисование таблицы програмным образом - штука неблагодарная и медленная, в целом, вы можете в шаблоне нарисовать хоть десяток таблиц, а приложение пусть удаляет лишние при формировании документа, подумайте в этом направлении. Грубо говоря, в шаблоне может быть шапка таблицы с одной строкой, а приложение при заполнении данными будет просто добавлять нужное количество строк.